# Having an issue with connection pools staying open (closing connections explicitly)

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have been getting an error on my application that the max pool size was reached:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

We have an internal function which returns a `DataReader`. Inside of this function, we are using the `ExecuteReader` method, which is given the value `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection`.  After reading the data we need, we are calling both `.Close` and `.Dispose` on the `DataReader` which is returned by this function.

On a side note, I also tried implementing a different method in which I did the `using` tag on my connection and still saw this as "Sleeping" in the database.

I ran the query below to get the connections which are still in sleeping status. At any time we are seeing about 40 or so listed as "sleeping". I grabbed the SQL Script being used here, traced this back to where they were being used in the application and triple checked the `DataReader`s are being closed.

> SELECT sp.spid , sp.hostname , sp.program_name , sp.loginame
>   ,sp.login_time, sp.status  , CAST(text AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS SQLScript 
>   FROM sys.sysprocesses sp CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text
>   (sp.sql_handle)   where program_name='.Net SqlClient Data Provider' and
>   loginame='[LoginNameForSql]'  order by SQLScript

Is there anything else I need to do to make sure these connections are being closed? Our team is extremely confused because all of us have double and triple checked that our readers are closed and diposed after using them.

Function to get Data Reader:

> ```
>         SqlConnection conn = OpenConnection();
>         SqlDataReader rdr = null;
>
>         //    try
>         //    {
>         SQL = strSQL;
>
>         CommandBehavior intBehavior = CommandBehavior.CloseConnection;
>
>         using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
>         {
>             cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
>             cmd.CommandTimeout = Timeout;
>             rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(intBehavior);
>             cmd.Parameters.Clear();
>         }
>
>       return rdr;
> ```

using said function:

> ```
>        var rdr = FunctionReturningDataReader();
>         if (rdr != null)
>         {
>             if (rdr.HasRows)
>             {
>                 while (rdr.Read())
>                 {
>                 }
>             }
>          }
>             rdr.Close();
>             rdr.Dispose();
> ```

EDIT: I increased the max pool size to 200 and haven't seen this error in our application since 3 days ago.

Comment: Also, rather than calling Dispose, you should wrap them in a Using block.

Comment: A pool will always have open "sleeping" connections that aren't in use, you'll have to pay attention to the available connections reported by the pool itself.  Only the pool knows which connections are/aren't allocated to calling code.  Also here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx notice the connection is in a `using(){}`.  You'd probably have to over-ride `DataReader` if you want to hook it to a connection and then close the connection when it is disposed...  How does the reader know it's the only call on this connection?

Comment: Added some more code, thanks!

Comment: Obvious question - are you sure that it's this method that is *leaking* the connections? (It may be the one that is identified by a stack trace on the exception, but that just tells you the method that discovered that the pool was exhausted)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am unsure of this, which is why I am asking here. I traced back using what SQL Script was last used for the "sleeping" items and all those have been closed.

Comment: @ebyrob I just did some more debugging and removed one of the calls to the DB which was set as "sleeping" This SPID no longer shows in the database, which tells me it is not being leaked somewhere else. It must be on this call. I also removed the using from the cmd inside my function, and this had no effect one way or another.

Comment: @shenn You do realize a pooled connection will show "sleeping" in SQL (since it is a live active connection) even if it is not being used and is available for use in the pool (but not allocated)?  I believe this was the very first point I tried to get across to you.  You would have to be using perf counter: `NumberOfActiveConnections` to find out anything useful here.  (Unless you're instrumenting the pool yourself manually...)

Comment: so even if you have all readers and connections closed properly inside of using statements, you will still have sleeping connections for these?

Comment: @shenn Yes, absolutely.  Very likely 40 is your Min or Max Connection Pool size...  Or it could be the avg number of concurrent connections.

Answer (score 1):

My concern would be that you are closing the connection but it is not going out of scope and getting disposed (quickly?).

I don't see that FunctionReturningDataReader() adds that much value.
Don't fool around - open a connection as late a possible and close it and dispose it as early as possible.
I would do that in line and put the SQLconnection in a using.
[SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
private static void ReadOrderData(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString =
        "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";

    using (SqlConnection connection =
               new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command =
            new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        // Call Read before accessing data. 
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ReadSingleRow((IDataRecord)reader);
        }

        // Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

I have had answers voted down for not putting reader in a using
This is from the documentation and I have found reader.Close() to be sufficient
If you feel the need to put reader in a using then do so

Comment: Down vote care to comment?  If you have something to add then do so.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are also closing the Database Connection object, and not just the DataReader.  Having an open Connection to the database will fill your connection pools.

Comment: I thought using CommandBehavior.CloseConnection; would do this, no?

Comment: @shenn - that is, indeed, what it should do.

Comment: Yep, I missed that part, sorry.